# ¿Cómo implementar un objeto en un método constructo?

Tags: java, clase

Debo sustituir las variables centroX y centroY de la clase Círculo por un objeto Punto y no se cómo implantar el objeto dentro del constructo de Círculo.

Dejo abajo ambos códigos.

**Clase círculo:**

```
private double radio;
private String color;
private int centroX, centroY;

/**Crea un punto como centro del círculo*/
Punto centro = new Punto(centroX, centroY);

/** Crea in círculo de radio r, color c y cen tro en (px,py)*/
public Círculo (double r, String c, int px, int py){
    radio = r; color = c; px = centroX; py = centroY;
}
```

**Clase Punto:**

```
private int x;
private int y;
   
/**Crea un punto(abs, ord)*/
public Punto (int abs, int ord){
    x = abs;
    y = ord;
}
```

//Actualización del código. 
**Clase círculo**:

```
    private double radio;
    private String color;
    private int centroX, centroY;
    
    /**Propiedad como centro del círculo*/
    private Punto centro;
    
    /** Crea in círculo de radio r, color c y cen tro en (px,py)*/
    //Es un método constructor, ya que tiene el mismo nombre de la clase
    // y se usa para crear un objeto, en este caso el "Círculo".
    //No llevan el tipo de dato a devolver
    public Círculo (double r, String c, Punto centro){
    radio = r; color = c; this.centro = centro;
    }
```

**Prueba Círculo:**

```
public class pruebaCirculo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Círculo n = new Círculo (150,"amarillo",new Punto(20,35));
    System.out.println(n.toString());
    }
}
```

**Salida de texto de la consola:** 
Círculo de radio 150.0,de color amarillo y centro (0,0).

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta el método `toString()` de la clase `Circulo` pulsando en [edit], puede que el problema esté ahí. O, mejor aún, pon la clase `Círculo` completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes crear una instancia de ninguna clase en el cuerpo de otra clase. Lo correcto sería recibir los parámetros en el Constructor y dentro de él crear la instancia de la propiedad de tipo `Punto`. O mejor aún, si te es permitido (ignoro si es un ejercicio y te requieren sí o sí pasar valores `x` e `y`  en parámetro), declaras un parámetro de tipo `Punto` en el Constructor y lo pasas ya instanciado al crear tu objeto `Círculo`.

Te advierto además de que en cualquier caso, estas dos propiedades serían redundantes en la clase: `int centroX, centroY` (ver el apartado que he agregado al final: **Optimizando el código** para entender por qué es redundante).

Veamos una posible solución, respetando tu Constructor con dos parámetros destinados a la propiedad de tipo `Punto`:

```
class Círculo {

    private double radio;
    private String color;
    
    /**Propiedad Punto como centro del círculo*/
    private Punto centro;
    
    /** Crea in círculo de radio r, color c y cen tro en (px,py)*/
    public Círculo (double r, String c, int px, int py){
        this.radio = r; 
        this.color = c; 
        this.centro=new Punto(px, py);
    }
}
```

Veamos otra posibile solución en la cual podrías  declarar en el Constructor un parámetro de tipo `Punto`, en ese caso tendrías que informar a la clase pasándole una instancia de `Punto`. Si te es permitido hacerlo así, esta opción es mucho mejor.

```
class Círculo {

    private double radio;
    private String color;
    
    /**Propiedad Punto como centro del círculo*/
    private Punto centro;
    
    /** Crea in círculo de radio r, color c y cen tro en (px,py)*/
    public Círculo (double r, String c, Punto centro){
        this.radio = r; 
        this.color = c; 
        this.centro=centro;
    }
}
```

En este segundo caso el constructor se llamaría así:

```
Círculo c = new Círculo( 1.1, "a", new Punto (2,4) );
```

### Optimizando el código

Decía que las propiedades `int centroX, centroY` serían redundantes, porque puedes obtener esos valores desde la clase `Punto`. Pues una de las grandes bondades de la POO es que te permite programar un objeto de modo que te provea todo lo que necesites de él.

Digamos que programas así la clase `Punto`:

```
public class Punto {
    private int x;
    private int y;
       
    /**Crea un punto(abs, ord)*/
    public Punto (int abs, int ord){
        x = abs;
        y = ord;
    }

    /**Con este método obtendrías las coordenadas*/
    public String getCoordinates (){
        return String.format("%d,%d",x,y);
    }
}
```

Ahora, el método `toString()` de la clase `Círculo` podría escribirse así:

```
    @Override
    public String toString (){
        return String.format("Círculo de radio %f,de color %s y centro (%s)",radio,color,centro.getCoordinates());
    }
```

Como podrás apreciar aquí: `centro.getCoordinates()` usamos el método `getCoordinates()` de la clase `Punto` para obtener la información de los valores `x` e `y`, evitando así tener en la clase `Círculo` dos propiedades que serían redundantes, pues existirían como miembros de `Círculo` (sin necesidad) y también existirían en `centro`, que es un objeto de la clase `Punto`.

Igualmente, si necesitaras obtener las propiedades `x` e `y` por separado, se supone que cada una de ellas tendrá su *getter*  en la clase `Punto` y por tanto, desde `Circulo`  podrás obtener su valor mediante una llamada del tipo `centro.getX()` y `centro.getY()`, asumiendo que así se llaman los *getter*.

Comment: Me gusta más el segundo caso

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por responder, sin embargo no he conseguido hacerlo funcionar. Dejo aquí el código por si me puedes ayudar:

Comment: Vale, ya lo he solucionado. Tenía mal escrito el método toString que me devolvía los parámetros de círculo, teniendo que me devolviera centroX y centroY en lugar de centro.toString(). Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda.